# I can´t run .php pages on my Microsoft Azure Web Aplication

Tags: php, azure, web, html

I'm trying to hoost a website on Microsoft Azure and I did it. But when I enter in my website to a .php page the browser answer with the next error message: "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred."

Before that, it returned a 500 error code, but searching the internet I tried to configure de Handler Mappings option (I dont know if I did it good or not, but now that is the new error message).

Is there any required configuration I have to do in order to make .php pages work? I have the "shared" payment plan, Do I need a better payment plan in other to do it?

Thank you!

Comment: how do you deploy your application? if you go to https://{yoursite}.scm.azurewebsite.net/debugconsole, and navigate to site/wwwroot, do you see your files?

Comment: I use FTP to upload files/pages to my Web App, and I can see my files in that site.

Answer (score 1):

When I knew there wasnt any extra configuration to run PHP I realized that the only one thing I changed was the **Handler Mapping options, so I disabled it and tried with a simple phpinfo()** in a index.php .

Exactly, the error was a bad php code. Thank you very much.

NOTE: Other person said me how to get logs for php 500 errors, you can find how to do it [HERE](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Troubleshooting-PHP-errors).

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that PHP is enabled for you Azure Web App.  Go to the Web App in the Azure Portal, click **Settings** and then **Application Settings**.  There is a dropdown labeled **PHP version**.  Make sure it is not set to "Off" (select your preferred version).  Then select Save.

Comment: I have selected the 5.4 php version since I created de Web App.